# Explanation on the ending of Elysium

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, elysium

In the ending of [Elysium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium_%28film%29), Spider and Max reach Elysium's main data-center and realize that the activation of the program will kill Max.

Why is it not possible for Max to be resurrected. We have seen Kruger to be resurrected so easily then what is the complication in resurrecting Max?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My initial thought has been muddied by trying to find a clip of the scene of the Kruger 'resurrection'.  Everything I've come across online says that Kruger was just near death, not actually dead.  Where as Max is actually dead dead, so he cannot be resurrected.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium_%28film%29):

> With the lockdown lifted, Kruger's ship departs for Elysium, but a
>   scuffle ensues, causing the ship to crash land into Elysium. Max, Frey
>   and Matilda are apprehended from the wreckage, while Kruger is
>   severely disfigured and near death.

From FilmSchoolRejects

> 1. How does the healing machine know to give Kruger a full beard? One of the most amazing moments in the movie is when we learn that Kruger,
>      in spite of having his face blown off, is not actually dead
>      (apparently the blood loss that would come with that wasn’t as much as
>      you think) - See more at:
>      http://www.filmschoolrejects.com/features/12-big-questions-left-unanswered-by-elysium.php/2#sthash.hOXj38HI.dpuf

However, my memory of the movie is that Kruger was dead dead, but his brain was in good shape so he could be brought back, where as Max's brain get's 'fried' resulting in him not being able to be resurrected.

Unfortunately, without the clip to listen to the henchmen's dialogue again, either or both may be true.

Comment: Kruger's resurrection was the weirdest scene for me (specially beard part). I didn't remember any conversation about Max's brain get's fried up. Yup i remember that saying them kruger can be resurrected because his brain is ok but kruger were definitely dead before resurrection.

Comment: I remember them talking about his brain getting fried both when they complete the hijacking and when they are overriding elysium.  I think it had something to do with the fact that everything was encrypted.